# How to plot two different curves with different timestamps in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, plot, curve-fitting

For my research I did two experiments at a different time period. How can I plot two curves in one plot to see the difference between the curves? The timestamps are different (datetime is used for the x-axis), this makes it different to plot all the curves in one plot. I need to plot the orange curves in one plot.

[image: First curve]

[image: Second curve]

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to reindex your dataframes (dataframe.reindex()) and then plot against the index. If you want to plot against a datetime, you could consider subtracting a time offset from the times in your later experiment using pandas.Timedelta.

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamps are different"? Do you have different time resolution or do you have a time offset between the two (or both)?

Comment: @ecc98 Is there less data in the bottom picture than in the first one? If so, then you need to synchronize both graphs. That is, to understand by what criteria the indices of one graph will correspond to another graph along the x-axis. 
If the date-time of the beginning and end of both charts are the same, then everything will be easier. Where there is less data, you can apply resample.

Comment: The first experiment is measured in three days and the second experiment is measured within one day. Both are measured on a different date and time, (now the x-axis is the date and time, so this will never fit two curves in one plot). My goal is to compare the pattern of the curves with each other.

Comment: @ecc98 place the link to the file, so it will be easier.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zvjA-MhnMExIzKkffVTjKPQ8_iwHztO5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TFobNQDgOGWvsqIuGu_x9taXK7dTtQLI_tSDhFlZFIY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: twin axis might help

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `twiny`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x1l = np.linspace( 0, 6,150 )
s1 = np.sin( x1l )

x2l = np.linspace( 126, 132, 166 )
s2 = np.sin( x2l ) 

fig = plt.figure( )

ax=fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
tx = ax.twiny()
ax.plot( x1l, s1, c="red" )
tx.plot( x2l, s2, c="blue" )

ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
tx.tick_params(axis='x', colors='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: Test for two sine curves with large time offset]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of comparing this data would be to reindex your two dataframes such that their indices overlap and you can plot against them. I can't open the links to the data you provided so I created two dataframes myself. Each spans a different time period and has a different sample frequeny.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Two time bases
t1 = np.arange(datetime(2022, 8, 25), datetime(2022, 8, 25, 5), timedelta(seconds=1)).astype(datetime)
t2 = np.arange(datetime(2022, 8, 29), datetime(2022, 8, 29, 7), timedelta(seconds=2)).astype(datetime)
enter code here

# Two dataframes, each with two measurements
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "measurement1": np.sin(0.001 * np.arange(0, len(t1))),
    "measurement2": np.cos(0.001 * np.arange(0, len(t1)))}, index=t1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "measurement1": np.sin(0.0015 * np.arange(0, len(t2))),
    "measurement2": np.cos(0.0015 * np.arange(0, len(t2)))}, index=t2)
```

Plotting them we can see it would be hard to compare if we use the datetime for the x-axis:
[image: hard to compare plot]

To fix this you can create an index for each dataframe. Both indices will start at zero and terminate at the length of the largest dataframe, but they will have different step sizes:

```
index1 = np.arange(0, max(len(df1), len(df2)), step=max(len(df1), len(df2)) / len(df1))
index2 = np.arange(0, max(len(df1), len(df2)), step=max(len(df1), len(df2)) / len(df2))

# Set the new indices
df1 = df1.set_index(keys=index1)
df2 = df2.set_index(keys=index2)
```

Now plot:

```
plt.plot(df1.index, df1["measurement1"], label="m1, df1")
plt.plot(df1.index, df1["measurement2"], label="m2, df1")
plt.plot(df2.index, df2["measurement1"], label="m1, df2")
plt.plot(df2.index, df2["measurement2"], label="m2, df2")
plt.legend()
```

[image: easy to compare plot]